# Referencing variable's element attributes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reference

I'm trying to understand JS referencing.

```
<a id="ohnoes" href="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-sounds/rpg/giant-no.mp3">What does Oh Noes say?</a>`
```

So I reference the above tag here in this function:

```
var ohnoesEl = document.getElementById("ohnoes");
var onOhNoesClick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var audioEl = document.createElement("audio");
    audioEl.src = "https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-sounds/rpg/giant-no.mp3";
    audioEl.autoplay = "true";
    document.body.appendChild(audioEl);
    };
```

why does this work:

```
audioEl.src = "https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-sounds/rpg/giant-no.mp3";
```

but not this:

```
audioEl.src = ohnoesEl.href;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have just tested your code, and it turns out that href works just fine.

```
<a id="a1" href="https://www.google.ca">Google</a>
<button onclick="changeAudio(event)">Click Me</>

<script>
var a1 = document.getElementById('a1')

function changeAudio(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  var audio = document.createElement('audio')
  audio.src = a1.href
  document.body.appendChild(audio)
}
</script>
```